# Using attributes of $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

To be honest, I do not know if my problem is related to jQuery of related to the plugin I'm using.

I use the plugin RateYo (http://prrashi.github.io/rateYo/) to display stars on our website. The number of stars that need to be shown, are given in an attribute of the div:

```
<div id="rating-avg" class="rateyo" rating="<?php echo $avg_rating; ?>" preset="true"></div>
```

Then, I call the plugin RateYo by calling home.js, which contains:

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rateYo").rateYo({
        rating: $(this).attr('rating'),
        readOnly: $(this).attr('preset')
    });
});
```

});

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The plugin does kick in and creates stars, but the variables $(this).attr('rating') and $(this).attr('preset') are not used. The rating is not displayed, but instead empty stars are shown.

When I use the following code, the rating is shown perfectly:

```
    $("#rating-avg").rateYo({
        rating: $("#rating-avg").attr("rating"),
        readOnly: $("#rating-avg").attr("preset")
    });
```

Unfortunately, I need the plugin to kick in by class, not id. We have a variable number of ratings on the site, so selecting them by ID isn't an option.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your value of `this` will not be correct and you were using the wrong capitalization for your class name.  You can probably make it work like this:

```
$(".rateyo").each(function() {
     var item = $(this);
     item.rateYo({
         rating: item.attr('rating'),
         readOnly: item.attr('preset')
     });
});
```

---

Note, you should probably be using HTML5 data attributes rather than your own custom attributes:

```
<div id="rating-avg" class="rateyo" data-rating="<?php echo $avg_rating; ?>" data-preset="true"></div>

$(".rateyo").each(function() {
     var item = $(this);
     item.rateYo({
         rating: item.data('rating'),
         readOnly: item.data('preset')
     });
});
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks very much! Thinking about it, I see the error in the logic I used. Apart from solving this specific issue, I've learned how to handle this in the future.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing to `rateYo` in your jQuery code, while the class attribute contains `rateyo` without a capital 'Y'.

Comment: This is not the only issue as they also have an issue with the use of `this`.